# How to show and hide page in side menu IONIC2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to create side menu in ionic2. But, I have no idea how to show and hide an option inside menu.
I want to show some option inside menu, before login and after login.

```
Before login             After login
---------                ---------
Home                     Home
Login                    Myprofile
                         Logout
```

app.ts

```
pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;
    pagess: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

    this.pages= [
          { title: 'Home', component: HomePage},
          { title: 'Login', component: LoginPage}
        ];

    this.pagess = [
          { title: 'Home', component: HomePage},
          { title: 'Myprofile', component: MyprofilePage},
          { title: 'Logout', component: HomePage}
        ];

enableMenu(loggedIn: boolean) {
    this.menu.enable(loggedIn, 'loggedInMenu');
    this.menu.enable(!loggedIn, 'loggedOutMenu');
  }
```

> I dont know how to set enableMenu

app.html

```
<ion-menu id="loggedOutMenu" [content]="content">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>

  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-menu id="loggedInMenu" [content]="content">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pagess " (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>

  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

login.ts (login is check in myphpfile)

```
login() {
       this.api.getLogin(this.username, this.password).subscribe(
   data => {

     let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: "Please wait...",
      duration: 1000
    });
    loader.present();
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
   },
   err =>  {

    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Warning!',
      subTitle: 'incorrect!',
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
  }
  );

}
```

Comment: if you are haveing success call back make the page view if you are not login then do't show use `*ngIf` to achive this

Comment: what is the use of sidemenu before login?

Comment: @varunaaruru before login `setroot=home` and side menu have `home` `login` and after login success `setroot=home` and side menu have `home` `myprofile` `logout`

Comment: @MohanGopi you have example for me T-T

Comment: what i was trying to say is, its a good practice to keep menu after user logged in or registration because there will be no use  of sidemenu in those pages.. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @fongfuse place some code so that i can debug and give some outpu

Comment: I have done something like this in my app. Need your code from where you are creating Menu options. I guess both from `app.html` and `app.ts`.

Comment: Please remove your code from answers section and edit your Question with the code. :) Just rules.

Comment: @SagarKulkarni ok sorry I remove this and I edited my this post

Comment: @MohanGopi I edited ,my code is a above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by subscribing/listening to the `loggedIn` event. Now, this is different than your normal login. You need to check if you are logged in.

Your app.html code will remain like this:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)" *ngIf='p.isVisible'>
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>

  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

Now here is the major change in `app.ts`.

```
pages: Array<{title: string, component: any, isVisible: boolean}>;

constructor(){
  this.api.isLoggedIn().subscribe(loggedIn => {
    this.pages= [
      { title: 'Home', component: HomePage, isVisible: true},
      { title: 'Login', component: LoginPage, isVisible: !loggedIn},
      { title: 'Myprofile', component: MyprofilePage, isVisible: loggedIn},
      { title: 'Logout', component: LogoutPage, isVisible: loggedIn}
    ];
  });
}
```

Now, your `isLoggedIn()` is a method, which returns an Observable, when the state of login is changed. It's data is `boolean`. You already might have this in your API like firebase has or you need to maintain/write it. Let me know what you are using and I will update my answer.

Comment: I do not use firebase. I check login with mysql ,What do you want to see? sorry my english and programming is not good. T_T

Comment: Where is your SQL hosted? Are you using HTTP GET/POST call for getting values from it? Anyways, it does not matter. You can maintain the login information locally also.

Comment: yes I using HTTP GET call for getting values from it. Can using `storage` for maintain the login information ? I want to example

Comment: Ok. I am implementing the same. Will update you soon.

Comment: Hey I have found an answer to this. Will update my answer soon. You need to use `Events` from `ionic-angular`. The answer is actually there in https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136479/discussion-between-sagar-kulkarni-and-fongfuse).

Comment: hey sorry I'm late . but I can do it!! thank a lot .

Comment: If I have to new question, I will ask you. hahaha

Comment: hi @SagarKulkarni how system will "isLoggedIn()" after login?