# Ionic 2. Check if Logged in during the launching of the app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

How do I check if user is logged in, when launching the app. If logged in, direct the user to the homepage, else direct the user to the LoginPage.

I want to store a boolean value after logging in successfully to the storage. When I launch the app, I want to see if the storage contains something?

```
this.storage.get('name').then((name) => {
    console.log('Your name is', name);
    this.sessa = name;
    console.log('Your name is',  this.sessa );
});
if(this.sessa == null){
    this.rootPage = LoginPage;
}
else if (this.sessa != null) {
    this.rootPage = HomePage;
}
```

Or in other words. How can I pass a value from the login page to the app.component.ts after a successful login. Thanks

Comment: According to your question, does not matter as in any case you are redirecting to Homepage. Do you mean, if not logged in then redirect to LoginPage?

Comment: @sagar Kulkami. Yes

Answer (score 1):

From the comments and solution I am reading, I think you need to fix a flow. Let me do that for you:

1. App launches.
2. Check if some user has already logged in.
3. If yes, go to HomePage. If not, go to LoginPage.

Now, this is really easy. As your name was not loaded by the time you were checking `if(this.sessa == null)`, it was failing. Also, I think having a boolean value in your storage for `isLoggedIn` would be a better idea than making sense out of name variable. Fixing in your code like this:

```
this.storage.get('isLoggedIn').then((isLoggedIn) => {
    console.log('Is Logged in : ', isLoggedIn);
    this.loggedIn = isLoggedIn;
    if(!this.loggedIn){
        this.rootPage = LoginPage;
    }
    else if(this.loggedIn) {
        this.rootPage = HomePage;
    }
});
```

Now, to answer your second question, about you wanting to pass value from LoginPage to app.component.ts, you need to create an Event for this, subscribe to it from app.component.ts and publish it when login is done.

Check out Events in ionic 2 documentation [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Events/). Also, I already have answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42405722/how-to-show-and-hide-page-in-side-menu-ionic2/42411773#42411773). Go through the ionic team's conference app [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app). They have done it. Please ask for specifics if this does not help you.

Comment: Kulkami. in the login page. I am passing this value: this.storage.set('isLoggedIn', this.login.username); and in the app.component.ts. I have these values: loggedIn: boolean; this.loggedIn = false;     this.storage.get('isLoggedIn').then((isLoggedIn) => {
      console.log('Is Logged in : ', isLoggedIn);
      this.loggedIn = isLoggedIn;
      if (!this.loggedIn) {
        this.rootPage = LoginPage;
      }
      else if (this.loggedIn) {
        this.rootPage = Home;
      }
    }); still not working

Comment: This will not work if you have not implemented `Events`. Just have a look at the conference app code. Also, do not set `this.storage.set('isLoggedIn', this.login.username);` username as a boolean value. When user is logged in, `this.storage.set('isLoggedIn', true);`. When logged out, `this.storage.set('isLoggedIn', false);`

Comment: Happy to help. :) Accept it as an answer then. :)

Comment: @JamesJavaCard If it helped please accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Place some conditional logic in your component for the app.component.ts file, if logged in set the rootPage to your home page otherwise set the rootPage to be the component which is your login page.

Comment: @JamesJavaCard Don't add it as a comment, edit your question.

Comment: @Jay Ordway, it works fine.  But I want to store the value name to the storage after I login. see here:  this.storag.get('name'). Then after launching the app again, it will check if storage contain something, which should be, then direct me to the hoe page. Thanks